# PowerShell Copy-Script

Tags: powershell, copy

I want to write a PowerShell script, which has to copy the content of certain named subfolders from a lot of parent folders.

I have a lot of project folders that all own a sub- or sub-sub-folder called "VKS". What I want to do is to copy all the "VKS"-Folders from all of those folders to a certain path, so all of them are in one common folder.

So the script would need to walk the whole directory and search for the folders called "VKS" and copy their content somewhere.

I've been trying for hours now but I can't figure it out and my PowerShell skills are not enough.

Comment: Copying multiple folders named `VKS` to the same directory would obviously result in naming conflicts - so how do you want to rename them? :)

Comment: Yes ure right. Well if it's possible like VKS1, VKS2, ......

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to find your source directories:

```
$GCIArgs = @{Path      = "\\servername\sharename\VKS*"
             Recurse   = $True
             Directory = $True}
$Source = (Get-ChildItem @GCIArgs).FullName | 
  Where-Object {$($($_).Substring(($_).Length-3),3) -eq "VKS"}
```

This will find them no matter how deep in the tree they reside. The Where-Object filters any directories that START with VKS like VKS1 or VKShare, etc.

The rest of the script should be easy after you figure out how to handle the naming conflicts pointed out by Mathias.

Here's my sample run results:

```
PS> $GCIArgs = @{Path      = "\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\test*"
             Recurse   = $True
             Directory = $True}
$Source = (Get-ChildItem @GCIArgs).FullName | 
  Where-Object {$($($_).Substring(($_).Length-4),4) -eq "Test"}


PS> $Source
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\Archived Files\Business\ASCC\Excel\Payroll\Test
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\Archived Files\Business\Jordan Investments\Test
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\DELLXPS137000\BEKDocs\Excel\Test
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\DELLXPS137000\BEKDocs\Scripts\Test
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\DELLXPS137000\BEKDocs\Word\Test
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\DELLXPS8700\BEKDocs\Excel\Test
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\DELLXPS8700\BEKDocs\Scripts\Test
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\DELLXPS8700\BEKDocs\Word\Test
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\DELLXPS8920\BEKDocs\Excel\Test
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\DELLXPS8920\BEKDocs\Scripts\Test
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\DELLXPS8920\BEKDocs\Test
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\DELLXPS8920\BEKDocs\Word\Test
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\JanetsLaptop\JEMDocs\Scripts\Test
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\Misc\Test
\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\NAS-Downloads\Test

PS>
```